# How does Django handle template name clashes?

Tags: django, django-templates

...when several apps define similarly named templates outside of a proper hierarchy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template loaders are applied in the order you've defined in `settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

For example, if you have the `app_directories` loader running AFTER the `filesystem` loader and your template is located in the `filesystem` loader, the `app_directories` loader will never be used.

If you're talking about the `app_directories` loader specifically, it searches your app template folders in the order they are defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

If you have conflicting template names that are not on purpose (not some kind of override hierarchy), chances are you are better off prefixing each template folder with the app name.

```
# this is standard
myapp/templates/myapp/index.html 
myapp2/templates/myapp2/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear on what you mean.  When you are specifying a template you should name it appropriately and specify it exactly.  If you mean something like the admin that chooses the "best" template from a list of templates, it's uses a simple algorithm to find the best match.  It does this simply by passing a list of templates to loader.select_template and the first one that is valid is used.

Comment: I was just curious if template are loaded once and cached at startup, which would impact how Django behaves if it finds several templates that share a name.